# php code not working for SOAP API, TNT

Tags: php, soap

I am working on TNT SOAP based API, I am using below code but gets only error, I can`t understand what I am doing wrong ?

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout",120);
$client = new SoapClient('https://uat.tntexpress.com.au/Webservices/Conservice/ConsignmentService.svc?wsdl');

$params = array(
   'payingAccount' => '20003191',
   'UserName' => 'NEX-APIT',
   'Password' => 'NEX_APIPWT'
);

$response = $client->__soapCall('ProcessConsignmentRequest',$params);

print_r($response);
```

**I am getting this error :**

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] The creator of this     fault did not specify a Reason. in D:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\soap.php:11
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\soap.php(11): SoapClient->__soapCall('ProcessConsignm...', Array)
>       #1 {main} thrown in     D:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\soap.php on line 11

Comment: So **what error are you getting** It might be useful for us to know that little bit of information

Comment: Well then try catching the Exception and print the error message see if there is anything useful in that. You should be using `try/catch` anyway if this is known to throw errors

Answer (score 0):

I found here the working code [tnt-express](https://github.com/winzou/tnt-express/tree/master/examples)